# Escape Level of Detail expression in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to build a calculation that takes their values from a Parameter.
The paramater is feeded from a string dimension.

Using SuperStore as an example, I've created a Parameter called `Country Par` containing all the `Country/Region` values.

For example, let's assume I have as a page filter `Country/Region` = `France` and the value for the `Country Par` = `United Kingdom`. Also, `Month(Order Date)` for Columns and `Measure Values` for Rows.

The measure values selected will be:

- `SUM(Sales)`
- `SUM(Comparable Country Sales)`

What I'm trying to achieve with the calculation is to retrive the values selected from the Parameter - in this case United Kingdom - ignoring whatever is selected as page filter. (France in the example).

And the same time I want to filter the Sales for United Kingdom ending the same month as Finland.

But due to the **FIXED** context, seems like LOD is not able to pickup the last month of Finland - Oct 2019.

**Comparable Country Sales**

```
{fixed MONTH([Order Date]):
sum(
if [Country/Region]=[Country Par]
and month([Order Date]) <= {max(if [Country/Region]="Finland" then month([Order Date]) end)}
then [Sales]

else null
END)}
```

This is only a representation of what I want to achieve in my original datasets, for obvious reasons I can't share the data.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions here-

- Create another parameter for selection of different country instead of hardcoding it.
- Despite your requirement of calculation on month-wise sales/measure, do not extract month([order date]) in conditional statement because it will return only a numeric value.  Check for date instead and later-on aggregate these month-wise if required.

I have proceeded like this..

(**Note:** In superstore data, I have played around on State field instead on Country as in latest version only US data is available)

`desired calculated field` with calculation as

```
{fixed DATETRUNC('month', [Order Date]):
sum(
if [State]= [Par1]
and ([Order Date]) <= {max(if [State] = [Par2] then ([Order Date]) end)}
then [Sales]
else null
END)}
```

See this works in my case

[image]

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks, I've used your concept of `DATETRUNC` to modify the original dataset. Using a second parameter doesn't really work in my case. 
What I did was to modify the dimension and use that as a fixed calculation.

Comment: Its Ok.  Use of second parameter was only a suggestion and not requirement.  Please also accept if it served the purpose, as usually desired on SO.